# Log4j - cannot link appender to logger using log4j.properties

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am writing a Java/Tomcat webserver application in which I need to use Log4j logging.  The Java code has the typical method of setting up a Logger, i.e.:

```
Logger theLogger = Logger.getLogger( "<logger name>" );
```

I am trying to link a file appender to this logger by using a log4j.properties file.  The contents of this file are:

```
log4j.logger.<logger name> = TRACE, LOGFILE

log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=trace.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

If my understanding is correct, this should setup a file appender in TRACE mode that will be linked to .  However, whenever I run the JVM, I am getting the output that the appender cannot be found:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (<logger name>).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for 
more info.
```

I am running the JVM with the flag -Dlog4j.configuration="" and also the flag -Dlog4j.debug.  The log4j debug output seems to be suggesting that the log4j.properties file cannot be found:

```
log4j: Trying to find [<path to log4j.properties>] using context classloader 
WebappClassLoader
    context: 
    delegate: false
    repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
    ----------> Parent Classloader:
    org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@6574b225
     .
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (<logger name>).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for 
more info.
log4j: Trying to find [<path to log4j.properties>] using WebappClassLoader
    context: 
    delegate: false
    repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
    ----------> Parent Classloader:
    org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@6574b225
    class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [<path to log4j.properties>]
    using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource:
[<path to log4j.properties>]
```

I also have the path to the log4j.properties file in the Java Classpath, so I'm not sure why this cannot be found.  My main question is the reason that the appender cannot be found because the log4j.properties file cannot be found, or is it being found, but something is incorrect in the configuration of log4j.properties?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try to add rootlogger and move your logger after LOGFILE appender.

Comment: Thanks Babl!  I tried moving logger below appender, and adding rootlogger.  Now log4j.properties:

log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=trace.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger = TRACE, LOGFILE

log4j.logger.<logger name> = TRACE, LOGFILE

However, I get same results.  I also tried without rootLogger, and with rootLogger moved above appender, but same results.  Any other suggestions?